# Existence statements on algebraic cycles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

I am a novice in AG so my question might be a little naive.

Numerous deep conjectures in AG i.e. Hodge Conjecture, Tate Conjecture, etc are essentially existence statements about algebraic cycles.

My question is why are existence statements about algebraic cycles so hard to tackle.
Even the weakest existence theorems for cycles seem to be out of reach.

Thanks,